# django-tables2 to used with django-modeltranslation showing all the fields when listed

Tags: django-tables2, django-modeltranslation

I am using **django-tables2** with **django-modeltranslation** in one of my new projects. The site is using localization for english and french.
If I render the table directly in html everything works fine, but django_tables2 seems to pour everything out, ignoring the localization request.
Django-tables2 has a "localize/unlocalize" option for multilingual sites but it does not seem to work with django-modeltranslation.
Here is my setup.

### models.py

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

### translation.py

```
@register(DataSet)
class DataSetTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = (
        "name",
        "source",
        "data_type",)
```

### tables.py

```
class DataSetTable(tables.Table):
   name = tables.Column(order_by="name")

    class Meta:
        model = DataSet
        sequence = (
            "name",
            "source",
            "data_type",)
        unlocalize = ("id",)
        localize = (
           "name",
           "source",
           "data_type",)
```

### datasets.html

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}
    {% render_table table %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This table is rendered as follows:

| name | source | data_type | name_en | name_fr | source_en | source_fr | data_type_en | data_type_fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| content | content | content | content | content | content | content | content | content |
| content | content | content | content | content | content | content | content | content |

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: In the DataSetTable.Meta, have you tried specifying the columns based on what localization is being used? something like: `fields = ('name_en', 'source_en') if localization == "EN") else  ('name_fr', 'source_fr')`